# PHP counting elements in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please consider the following multidimensional array $standings:

```
Array ( [position] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) [name] => Array ( [0] => Tiger Woods [1] => Phil Mickleson [2] => J.B. Holmes [3] => Jim Furyk ) [score] => Array ( [0] => 69 [1] => 70 [2] => 71 [3] => 72 )
```

in more human readable format

```
(position - name - score):

1 - Tiger Woods - 69

2 - Phil Mickleson - 70

3 - J.B. Holmes - 71

4 - Jim Furyk - 72
```

How do I obtain a count of 4 instead of a 12 which is what a recursive array count would give me.

I've tried both the following examples. They give me total elements instead of just each row of elements which is what I want.

Example #1:

```
function countNested($arr) {
    return (count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($arr));
}
```

Example #2:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($standings as $t) {
    $count+= count($t); 
}
echo $count;
```

I could divide the number of rows by the number of columns, but there are cases where i'm only using a subset of records, and this might not suffice.

```
function countNested($arr) {
    return (count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($arr))/3;
}
```

When I run the function to generate the array, I'm keeping a count of the array elements, but... I can only return the array of the function and not the count.

Can you please suggest a way I might be able to do this efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with `$count = count($array['position'])` ?

Comment: Rikesh: nothing. I didn't know you could count an array inside an array. Thank you, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function cntArr($arra){
    foreach($array as $arr){
        return count($arr);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Did you mean:

<?php
function cntArr($array){
    foreach($array as $arr){
        return count($arr);
    }
}
?>

when i pass it the array i'm working with it returns nothing.

Comment: also, wouldn't this just return the amount of arrays within the main array? I need the amount of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($array['position'])
```

is what I was looking for!